# Change the log location (i.e., `LogDevice`) in a Ruby on Rails (version 6) application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 3 seems to have had a property in config for changing the output location of `Rails.logger`, [`config.log_path`](https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Configuration/Deprecated/log_path). That's been deprecated. Looking at a Rails 6 application, is this the way to do that now? Or did this config property get moved to something new?

```rb
  logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('log/blahblah.log')
  logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
  config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
config.paths['log'] = 'log/new_log_file.log'
```

You can read more about paths here:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application/Configuration.html#method-i-paths

Comment: Awesome. I saw the deprecation notice and tried `config.paths.log` instead but see now that `paths` is a `Hash`. Thanks